# How to make AngularJS example work properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found this example wand I want to use it in my tutorial project.

The problem is that in this

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['app.directives']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){                     
    $scope.roles = [
          {"id": 1, "name": "Manager", "assignable": true},
          {"id": 2, "name": "Developer", "assignable": true},
          {"id": 3, "name": "Reporter", "assignable": true}
    ];
    
    $scope.member = {roles: []};
    $scope.selected_items = [];
});

var app_directives = angular.module('app.directives', []);

app_directives.directive('dropdownMultiselect', function(){
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope:{           
            model: '=',
            options: '=',
            pre_selected: '=preSelected'
       },
       template: "<div class='btn-group' data-ng-class='{open: open}'>"+
        "<button class='btn btn-small'>Select</button>"+
                "<button class='btn btn-small dropdown-toggle' data-ng-click='open=!open;openDropdown()'><span class='caret'></span></button>"+
                "<ul class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenu'>" + 
                    "<li><a data-ng-click='selectAll()'><i class='icon-ok-sign'></i>  Check All</a></li>" +
                    "<li><a data-ng-click='deselectAll();'><i class='icon-remove-sign'></i>  Uncheck All</a></li>" +                    
                    "<li class='divider'></li>" +
                    "<li data-ng-repeat='option in options'> <a data-ng-click='setSelectedItem()'>{{option.name}}<span data-ng-class='isChecked(option.id)'></span></a></li>" +                                        
                "</ul>" +
            "</div>" ,
       controller: function($scope){
           
           $scope.openDropdown = function(){        
                    $scope.selected_items = [];
                    for(var i=0; i<$scope.pre_selected.length; i++){                        $scope.selected_items.push($scope.pre_selected[i].id);
                    }                                        
            };
           
            $scope.selectAll = function () {
                $scope.model = _.pluck($scope.options, 'id');
                console.log($scope.model);
            };            
            $scope.deselectAll = function() {
                $scope.model=[];
                console.log($scope.model);
            };
            $scope.setSelectedItem = function(){
                var id = this.option.id;
                if (_.contains($scope.model, id)) {
                    $scope.model = _.without($scope.model, id);
                } else {
                    $scope.model.push(id);
                }
                console.log($scope.model);
                return false;
            };
            $scope.isChecked = function (id) {                 
                if (_.contains($scope.model, id)) {
                    return 'icon-ok pull-right';
                }
                return false;
            };                                 
       }
   } 
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">    
    <dropdown-multiselect pre-selected="member.roles" model="selected_items" options="roles"></dropdown-multiselect>
    
    
    <pre>selected roles = {{selected_items | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

the property defined hard-coded:

```
  name
    id
```

So if name of my fields called another the example will not work.

Any idea what have I to change in my code to make the example work properly if fields called diffrent names?

Comment: this is way too broad as written.  The *simple* answer is that if your fields are named different, a find and replace would change their names.  But the way your question is worded, it sounds more like you aren't even sure what the code pasted does, and if you aren't sure, this isn't the right place to find someone to explain it to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['app.directives']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){                     
    $scope.roles = [
          {"id": 1, "name1": "Manager", "assignable": true},
          {"id": 2, "name1": "Developer", "assignable": true},
          {"id": 3, "name1": "Reporter", "assignable": true}
    ];
    
    $scope.member = {roles: []};
    $scope.selected_items = [];
    $scope.displayname = "name1";
});

var app_directives = angular.module('app.directives', []);

app_directives.directive('dropdownMultiselect', function(){
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope:{           
            model: '=',
            options: '=',
            displayname: '=',
            pre_selected: '=preSelected'
       },
       template: "<div class='btn-group' data-ng-class='{open: open}'>"+
        "<button class='btn btn-small'>Select</button>"+
                "<button class='btn btn-small dropdown-toggle' data-ng-click='open=!open;openDropdown()'><span class='caret'></span></button>"+
                "<ul class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenu'>" + 
                    "<li><a data-ng-click='selectAll()'><i class='icon-ok-sign'></i>  Check All</a></li>" +
                    "<li><a data-ng-click='deselectAll();'><i class='icon-remove-sign'></i>  Uncheck All</a></li>" +                    
                    "<li class='divider'></li>" +
                    "<li data-ng-repeat='option in options'> <a data-ng-click='setSelectedItem()'>{{option[displayname ]}}<span data-ng-class='isChecked(option.id)'></span></a></li>" +                                        
                "</ul>" +
            "</div>" ,
       controller: function($scope){
           console.log($scope.displayname );
           $scope.openDropdown = function(){        
                    $scope.selected_items = [];
                    for(var i=0; i<$scope.pre_selected.length; i++){                        $scope.selected_items.push($scope.pre_selected[i].id);
                    }                                        
            };
           
            $scope.selectAll = function () {
                $scope.model = _.pluck($scope.options, 'id');
                console.log($scope.model);
            };            
            $scope.deselectAll = function() {
                $scope.model=[];
                console.log($scope.model);
            };
            $scope.setSelectedItem = function(){
                var id = this.option.id;
                if (_.contains($scope.model, id)) {
                    $scope.model = _.without($scope.model, id);
                } else {
                    $scope.model.push(id);
                }
                console.log($scope.model);
                return false;
            };
            $scope.isChecked = function (id) {                 
                if (_.contains($scope.model, id)) {
                    return 'icon-ok pull-right';
                }
                return false;
            };                                 
       }
   } 
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">    
    <dropdown-multiselect pre-selected="member.roles" model="selected_items"  displayname ="displayname" options="roles"></dropdown-multiselect>
    
    
    <pre>selected roles = {{selected_items | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: I had exposed, one displayname property, to pass dynamic 'name' attribute. Similarly you can apply for 'id' attribute as well

Answer (score 2):

While I think it's perfectly fine with forcing input to use determined key as part of the API myself, it's entirely possible to customize that, by passing additional parameters into the directive.

```
.directive(function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            options: '=',
            keys: '='
        },
        template: "<div ng-repeat='option in options'> \
                {{option[key.id]}} - {{option[key.name]}} \
            <div>",
        controller: function($scope){
            // default if key is not specified
            if (!$scope.keys) $scope.keys = {id: 'id', name: 'name'};

            angular.forEach($scope.options, function(option){
                // refer to id by option[$scope.key.id]
                // refer to name by option[$scope.key.name]
            });
        }
    }
})
```

When you pass into directive you'll need to tell it which key is id and name respectively

```
$scope.test = [
    {serial: 123, product: 'apple'},
    {serial: 124, product: 'orange'}
]

$scope.keys = {id: 'serial', name: 'product'};

<dropdown-multiselect model="selected_items" options="test" keys="keys"></dropdown-multiselect>
```

Comment: maybe my question will sound silly but I am new to angularjs.
Do I have to put $scope.test = [
    {serial: 123, product: 'apple'},
    {serial: 124, product: 'orange'}
]

$scope.keys = {id: 'serial', name: 'product'};

to controller?

Comment: Yea. When you see $scope it usually means inside controller.